# Navigation does not work when I separate the component that I want rendered into another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-navigation

Currently I am trying to have a list view inside of a segmented control. I set up a segmented control in my main file, so that when the segment

**main.js**

```
{this.state.seg === 2 && (
   <List
     dataArray={datas}
     renderRow={data =>
       <ListItem
         button
         onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
       >
         <Left>
           <Text>
             {data.text}
           </Text>
         </Left>
         <Right>
           <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
         </Right>
       </ListItem>
     }
  />
)}
```

this works properly and navigates to a completely new page to the route that I want from navigate. However, if I try to separate it like this

**ListView.js**

```
class ListView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (         
      <List
        dataArray={datas}
        renderRow={data =>
          <ListItem
            button
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
          >
            <Left>
              <Text>
                {data.text}
              </Text>
            </Left>
            <Right>
              <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        } 
      />
    );
  } 
}
```

and **main.js** as

```
{this.state.seg === 2 && 
  <ListView />
}
```

my code does not work and it gives me the error that

undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation').

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the `navigation` prop down to your `ListView` so it has access to it:

```
{this.state.seg === 2 && 
  <ListView navigation={this.props.navigation} />
}
```